# Nuxt 3 - get ref from layout to component

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

What is the correct way to getBoundingClientRect (here i'm using vueuse) in a component by referencing a div that is in the layout that contains this component? I have tried various configurations but it always gives me various errors

layout > html:

```html
<footer ref="footergrid">
    <some-other-component />
</footer>
<child-comp />
```

layout > script

```js
<script setup>
const footergrid = ref()
provide(footergrid)
</script>
```

child-comp.vue:

```js
<script setup>
import { useElementBounding } from '@vueuse/core'
const extfootergrid = inject('footergrid')
const footergrid = reactive(useElementBounding(extfootergrid))
console.log(footergrid)
</script>
```

ERROR: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: element.getBoundingClientRect is not a function

Comment: `onMounted(() => console.log(document.querySelector('footer').getBoundingClientRect()))`

Answer (score 0):

Vue built-in function `provide()` takes two arguments - an injection key (mostly a string) and then the value. So you should use it like this: `provide('footergrid', footergrid)` to correctly pass the value down.